# Angular Material input field not showing correctly

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

The input field is not showing correctly and i add alredy add all imports from Angular Material.
[image]

```html
<p>
  <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
    <mat-label>Outline form field</mat-label>
    <input matInput placeholder="Placeholder">
    <mat-icon matSuffix>sentiment_very_satisfied</mat-icon>
    <!-- <mat-hint>Hint</mat-hint> -->
  </mat-form-field>
</p>
```